# Django GraphQL API with JWT authentication implementation still allows for unauthenticated requests from Postman get data. How do I fix this?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, graphql, django-graphql-jwt

I've built a Django API that uses [django-graphql-auth](https://pypi.org/project/django-graphql-auth/) and [django-graphql-jwt](https://django-graphql-jwt.domake.io/en/latest/) packages to implement authentication. I followed the package's documentation and got everything to work and everything is working from my Angular UI. The only issue is that even requests made from Postman without the Authorization header, are able to fetch the data from the graphql API.

This is my Django project's settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for myproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-)3@2sm6lgn_p83_t(l-44hd16ou5-qbk=rso!$b1#$fu*n2^rq'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'graphene_django',
    'graphql_jwt.refresh_token.apps.RefreshTokenConfig',
    'graphql_auth',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters'
]

GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'myproject.schema.schema',
    'MIDDLEWARE': [
        'graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware',
    ],
}

GRAPHENE_DJANGO_EXTRAS = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'graphene_django_extras.paginations.LimitOffsetGraphqlPagination',
    'DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE': 20,
    'MAX_PAGE_SIZE': 50,
    'CACHE_ACTIVE': True,
    'CACHE_TIMEOUT': 300    # seconds
}


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'common.utils.UpdateLastActivityMiddleware'
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'graphql_auth.backends.GraphQLAuthBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    "JWT_ALLOW_ANY_CLASSES": [
        "graphql_auth.mutations.Register",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.VerifyAccount",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.ResendActivationEmail",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.SendPasswordResetEmail",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.PasswordReset",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.ObtainJSONWebToken",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.VerifyToken",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.RefreshToken",
        "graphql_auth.mutations.RevokeToken",
    ],
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'common.utils.jwt_payload',
    "JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION": True,
    "JWT_LONG_RUNNING_REFRESH_TOKEN": True
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
#     }
# }

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'myprojectdb',
        'USER': 'myprojectadmin',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    '/var/www/static/',
)

# Media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# This is here because we are using a custom User model
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myapp.User"
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('graphql/', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True))),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Sample query:-

```
query users {
  users {
    id
    nickName
    lastLogin
  }
}
```

As you can see, I've followed all the necessary steps to accomodate the instructions in both the packages. How do I prevent unauthorized requests accessing my data?

**Updates:-**

I'm using [Django-graphql-extras](https://pypi.org/project/graphene-django-extras/) for pagination, filtering on my Graphql api. So the queries are all using the built-in methods from that package.

The mutations however are manual.

**Queries file:-**

```
from graphene_django.types import ObjectType
from .gqTypes import InstitutionType, UserType, GroupType
from graphene_django_extras import DjangoObjectField, DjangoFilterPaginateListField, LimitOffsetGraphqlPagination


class Query(ObjectType):
    institution = DjangoObjectField(
        InstitutionType, description='Single User query')
    user = DjangoObjectField(UserType, description='Single User query')
    group = DjangoObjectField(GroupType, description='Single User query')
    institutions = DjangoFilterPaginateListField(
        InstitutionType, pagination=LimitOffsetGraphqlPagination())
    users = DjangoFilterPaginateListField(
        UserType, pagination=LimitOffsetGraphqlPagination())
    groups = DjangoFilterPaginateListField(
        GroupType, pagination=LimitOffsetGraphqlPagination())
```

**Sample mutation code:-**

```
class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    class Meta:
        description = "Mutation to create a new User"

    class Arguments:
        input = UserInput(required=True)

    ok = graphene.Boolean()
    user = graphene.Field(UserType)

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, info, input=None):
        ok = True
        error = ""
        if input.name is None:
            error += "Name is a required field<br />"
        if len(error) > 0:
            raise GraphQLError(error)
        searchField = input.name
        searchField += input.title if input.title is not None else ""
        searchField += input.bio if input.bio is not None else ""
        searchField = searchField.lower()

        user_instance = User(user_id=input.user_id, title=input.title, bio=input.bio,
                             institution_id=input.institution_id, searchField=searchField)
        user_instance.save()
        return CreateUser(ok=ok, user=user_instance)
```

Comment: can you add any query or mutation please?

Comment: Not sure how that helps, but I've added a sample query that I am able to send via postman and get results. Without adding anythign to the headers. And I've also added what my `urls.py` looks like.

Comment: sorry, not the query that you do to get the data, I need the code of your declared query, for example User, where you do the filter and return.

Comment: Sorry that was my bad. I should have guessed. I've added it. I am using django-graphql-extras package for pagination, so I'm using their built-in methods for the query definition. I don't think they yet offer a way to write custom resolvers for those pagination/filter queries. I am using custom mutations though. I've added a sample one for you to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `login_required` decorator to your queries and mutations resolvers. Like this:

```
from graphql_jwt.decorators import login_required


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    viewer = graphene.Field(UserType)

    @login_required
    def resolve_viewer(self, info, **kwargs):
        return info.context.user
```

In your case put it after staticmethod decorator, like this:

```
@staticmethod
@login_required
def mutate():
    pass
```

Comment: I got this to work for the mutations. Thanks.

But I don't know what to do about the the built-in query definitions that come with the graphene-django-extras package. Would you have any idea? I did a preliminary search and couldn't get much information.

Comment: I don't use that lib so I don't know if this will works but I found this: https://github.com/eamigo86/graphene-django-extras/issues/41#issuecomment-449182006

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I actually found that same thing a bit after making the comment here. But I tried it and it didn't work. I just ended up writing my own custom query methods with my own pagination and filter solution. Thanks a lot for your help!